# MSSQL Query Executed But not updated in Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mssql-jdbc

I've both MYSQL and MSSQL and I tried in MYSQL its working but MSSQL query also executed but 0 rows are affected and checked in table not yet updated.

MYSQL QUERY:

```
UPDATE aqi_metrics 
SET stability=:stability ,risk=:risk,days=DATE(NOW( )) 
WHERE project=:project AND days=DATE(NOW( ))
```

MSSQL QUERY:

```
UPDATE aqi_metrics 
SET stability=31 ,risk=8,days=GETDATE() 
WHERE project='JupiterQA' AND days=GETDATE()
```

what is the error in MSSQL query?

Comment: What is the datatype of `days` column also what happens when you run `select * from aqi_metrics WHERE project='JupiterQA' AND days=GETDATE()`

Comment: `DATE(NOW( ))` is not the same as `GETDATE()`. Try`CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

GETDATE() returns a date time - so it will have the time in there too. You need to convert both to date data type to just compare the date. For example.

```
UPDATE aqi_metrics 
SET stability=31 ,risk=8,days=GETDATE() 
WHERE project='JupiterQA' AND CONVERT(date, days) = CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Comment: agree with this but for performance change to days >= CONVERT(date, getdate())